# Prevent Bootstrap navbar from collapsing and breaking

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I have a fixed bootstrap navbar at the bottom. It breaks to mobile view at 768px.
I'd like to prevent it, without re-compiling bootstrap.css.

Is there a simple way to do this, without touching bootstrap.css. I can write a new css though. Or change the HTML.

I removed..

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
```

to..

```
<ul class="nav navbar-right">
```

But it did not worked out.

**Here is my demo project:**

https://jsfiddle.net/qr3n0qyt/

Comment: @ZimSystem this does not work with boostrap 3. I've tried this with jsfille.

Comment: It will work but you'll need to restructure the navbar. You shouldn't have the responsive nav with all of the collapse and toggle. You should only have a `navbar-brand` and `navbar-nav`